# There are no two (the) same

Tags: articles

Is it correct to use "the" in this sentence?

**There are no two the same people in the world.**

or should it be?

**There are no two same people in the world.**

Is this OK?

**There are not two the same people in the world.**

Comment: I believe the second sentence is the only one correct.

Comment: You may also want to consider "There are no two people in the world the same", as a variant of "No two people in the world are the same".

Answer (score 3):

All of these are either wrong (#1 and #3) or just awkward (#2).  I suggest that you should say this as:

> "There are no two identical people in the world."

Or if you want to use the word "same":

> "There are no two people in the world who are the same."

Comment: Ta-ta! What makes them ungrammatical? The combination of "no" and "the same"? I see that "not" and "the same" are also wrong. Why?